# Angular Stripe implementation with two Public Key depend on the account type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two Stripe Public Key which may work depending on what country the user is going to have a payment.

in my environment.ts file

```
export const environtment = { 
MY_PUBLIC_KEY_CH: 'chqwqw32323erwrerererkey',
MY_PUBLIC_KEY_US: 'usqwqw32323erwrerererkey',
```

}

in my app.module.ts file

```
import { NgxStripeModule } from "ngx-stripe";


 @NgModule({
imports: [NgxStripeModule.forRoot(
if(accountType === 'China_Account') {
environment.MY_PUBLIC_KEY_CH
} else if(accountType === 'US_Account'){  
environment.MY_PUBLIC_KEY_US)
 }]})
```

Is it possible for a two key implementation?
I don't know how to implement the dual public key. Please Help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem using this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-stripe/v/7.4.4) the old StripeService.

import { Group } from '@app/shared/models/group';

import { GroupService } from '@app/shared/services/api-services/group.service';

export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

groupType: Group;

```
 constructor(
          private groupService: GroupService,
          private stripeApiService: StripeApiService,
          private stripeService: StripeService)
           { }
ngOnInit() {
this.service.getGroup(this.storedUser.Group).subscribe(group => {
this.groupType = group;
if(group.AccountType === 'China_Account'){
  this.stripeService.setKey(environment.MY_PUBLIC_KEY_CH);
} else {
  this.stripeService.setKey(environment.MY_PUBLIC_KEY_US);
}
```

})
}}